# Запрос через EntityGraph и Specification при FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Есть Entity для которой я делаю граф:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "entity-graph",
        attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode(value = "classRoom",subgraph = "teacher-subgraph")},
        subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "teacher-subgraph",attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("teacher")})})
public final class Teacher extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private ClassRoom classRoom;
```

Entity ClassRoom:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_room")
public final class ClassRoom extends BaseModel {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classRoom", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<Teacher> teacher = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classRoom",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<Pupil> pupil = new HashSet<>();
```

Делаю запрос через спецификацию:

```
public class TeacherSpecification {
    public static Specification<Teacher> findBy(String name) {
        return new Specification<Teacher>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Teacher> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                root = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                Join<Teacher, ClassRoom> teacherClassRoomJoin = root.join("classRoom");
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(teacherClassRoomJoin.get(Teacher_.NAME),name);

            }
        };
    }
```

В TeahcerRepository связываю граф:

```
public interface TeacherRepository extends CrudRepository<Teacher,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Teacher> {
    List<Teacher> findByName(String name);

    @EntityGraph(value = "entity-graph")
    List<Teacher> findAll(Specification specification);

}
```

Тестирование запроса:

```
@Test
public void testFinal() {
    Iterable<Teacher> findByFinal = teacherRepository.findAll(TeacherSpecification.findBy("Alla"));
    findByFinal.forEach(c-> System.out.println(c.getClassRoom().getId() + " " + c.getClassRoom().getName()));
    findByFinal.forEach(t-> System.out.println(t.getId() + " " + t.getSurname() + " " + t.getDiscipline()));
}
```

В консоль падает ошибка:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

Суть запроса, достать учителя, чтоб у него уже был класс загруженный через EAGER, где я допустил ошибку в логике?

Comment: а зачем в `subgraphs` достаете teacher? получается связка teacher -> classroom -> teacher. И еще вопрос, в `TeacherSpecification` делается join, можно же без него обратиться к teacher.name напрямую и запрос будет корректным, зачем  добавили join?

Comment: @MrFylypenko я рассуждал загрузи мне учителей связанных с классом, по поводу `TeacherSpecification`, явно сделать `join` чтобы потом вытащить имя класса и id класса, получается тут `subgraphs`в целом не нужен ?